# Python splitting with ( )

Tags: python, split

I have a list `a`.

```
a = ["I am (John) and my age is 19" , "I am (Tom) and my age is 19", "I am (Ken) and my age is 20"].
```

I would like to have another list `b` that only contains names

```
b= ["John", "Tom", "Ken"]
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have used split but not really sure how do I get those.

Comment: You'll likely need some regular expression to do this. Additionally, lists are populated with `[]`

Comment: Your syntax and terminology are wrong. Check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: How certain are you that all of the strings in list a will have exactly one parenthesized substring?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing a little function to extract a parenthesized substring from a string, and then apply that function to each element in the list. You'll need to do a little soul-searching to determine whether you're happy assuming that there will always be exactly one parenthesized substring in each string in the list, since this will determine how the function is written and what it returns, but once you've written that function it's easy:

```
list b = [extract_parenthesized_substring(s) for s in a]
```

The definition of `extract_parenthesized_substring` is left as an exercise for the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are created with `[]`, not `{}`.

Using `split` is not necessary, you can use `.index()` to find the positions of `"("` and `")"` in the string (assuming there is only one parenthesized substring) and create a substring using them:

```
a = ["I am (John) and my age is 19" , "I am (Tom) and my age is 19", "I am (Ken) and my age is 20"]
b=[]
for string in a:
    name=string[string.index("(")+1:string.index(")")]
    b.append(name)
```

Or you could write this as a `list comprehension`:

```
b=[string[string.index("(")+1:string.index(")")] for string in a]
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Tom', 'Ken']
```

Comment: Seems to me OP is in fact looking for the list comprehension.